# How to use images in CSS for Flask?

Tags: html, css, image, flask

My HTML has `<section id="banner">` and CSS has

```
#banner {
        padding: 12em 0 10em 0;

        background-image: url({{ url_for('static',filename = '../images/banner.jpg')}});

        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: 0.5em solid #5385c1;
    }
```

and few more @media stuff. But due to some issue Image is not able to load.
what is wrong here?
everything else is working. HTML images taken using `<img` are working.
How to import images in flask application through CSS?
My file structure is App->templates,static.  ,  static->CSS,Images. ,  templates->*.html ,  CSS>*.CSS

Comment: I can't shift my banner.jpg importing to HTML because I have some features given to it using CSS.

Comment: https://github.com/PrajjwalDatir/WebApp/issues/1

here's link to my code as well as issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the images are rendered using render_template() only so image must be rendered through *.html file.
So after importing image in html it solves the issue.
inline CSS gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are including the CSS from a `.css` file in the static directory.  Jinja2 does not proesses these static files.

If you wish to avoid putting this CSS block into the HTML template, then your best option is to hard code this URL into the CSS file:

```
background-image: url('/static/path/to/background.jpg');
```

> I have some features given to it using CSS.

Although you could try defining a separate CSS block within the template, which assigns only the `background-image` declaration to `#banner`, with the remainder of those declarations being defined in the `.css` file (then test your 'functionality')...

```
<style type='text/css'>
#banner
{
  background-image: url({{ url_for('static',filename = '../images/banner.jpg')}});
}
</style>
```